# AdventureWorksDW2008R2: is there a data lineage documentation available?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl, sample-data

AFAICS the Microsoft Sample database AdventureWorksDW2008R2 is based on AdventureWorks2008R2. Is there an SSIS ETL package available which creates AdventureWorksDW2008R2 database schema and data? And is there available a data mapping (data lineage) documentation (e.g in Excel) telling which fields in AdventureWorksDW2008R2 represents the data in the corresponding OLTP database, the AdventureWorks2008R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/#monolith) is the page you want.

The first link contains all the examples, but you should find the one you want scrooling down the page